# Elementary Topology Problem: What is $\tau_c$?

Tags: general-topology

This is the problem set I given by Munkres Topology (2014, 2nd int'l edition)

> Show that the collection $\tau_c$ given in Example 4 of §12 is a topology on the set X  where Example 4 of §12 is following picture

[image]

> Then, is the collection$$\tau _∞=\{U|X−U \text{is infinite or empty or all of }X\} 
> $$
>   a topology on $X$?

`My Question`

I can't understand what $\tau_c$ is on `Figure 13.4` . It looks $\tau_\infty$ refers to the infinite collection of $\tau_c$, but I am not sure of it either.

Any guidance to understand it right?

Comment: You are looking at Example 4 in Section 13, rather than in Section 12.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the right section! It's the example 4 on page 77, Let $\mathscr{T}_c$ be the collection of all subsets $U$ of $X$ such that $X- U$ is either countable or is all of $X$.